# i am finding it difficult to fix an error that is making a dictionary item not callable using a json file

Tags: python, json

i am trying to run a set of codes that will translate any word entered by a user using a 'json' file
but kept getting this error;

PS `E:\py files\dic> python .\app1.py`

`enter word: rain`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File ".\app1.py", line 7, in 
> print(translate(word))
> File ".\app1.py", line 5, in translate
> return data(w)
> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
> PS E:\py files\dic>

these are the codes input;

```py
import json
data=json.load(open("data.json"))

def translate(w):
    return data(w)
word=input("enter word: ")
print(translate(word))
```

Comment: what is sample data of `data.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

To access items of the `data` [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (`dict`), use square brackets (`[ ]`):

```
def translate(w):
    return data[w]
```

By using parentheses, you are telling Python to use `data` as a callable, i.e. like a function. As Python tells you, this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks alot, @Melebius. The square brackets was what i missed.

Comment: @DonmmanuelsVincentJibrin I am glad to have helped! If I could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/217657) my answer (✓). See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get` method of a dictionary to get the `w` from `data` or to return a default value if it's not in the dictionary.

```
def translate(w):
    return data.get(w, default_value)
```